# How to assign the attribute of an element with the content of another element in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

For example, I have an element like this:

```
<start loc="USA" city="York">
    <time date="2016-08-07">17:29</time>
</start>
```

and I have the following template in XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="start">
    <node name="test" timeTest=>

    </node>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I assign timeTest with the content of time in the first XML file?

Answer (score 1):

To populate an attribute of a literal result element, you can use an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)

```
<xsl:template match="start">
    <node name="test" timeTest="{time}">

    </node>
</xsl:template>
```